# TikZ: Override fill of shape based on one pgfkey with another in command

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, pgfkeys

I'm creating a package that generates a tikz picture based on a command with pgf key/value parameters. I want to have two parameters, one that specifies a base shape with a particular fill colour, and another that turns that fill "on" when false (to the specified colour), and "off" (to white) when true. I've created a simplified example below:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newboolean{shapecolour}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
 circle/.style={fill=red},
 square/.style={fill=green},
 triangle/.style={fill=yellow},
 blank/.style={fill=white},
 colourshape/.store in=\colourshape,
 colourshape=circle,
 nocolour/.store in=\nocolour,
 nocolour=false,
 circle/.pic={\draw [fill] circle(0.5); },
 square/.pic={\draw [fill] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;},
 triangle/.pic={\draw [fill] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (0.5, 1) -- cycle;},
 }

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\TestCommand}[1][]{
 \tikzset{colourshape=circle, nocolour=false, #1}
 \setboolean{shapecolour}{\nocolour}
 \pic[\ifthenelse{\boolean{shapecolour}}{blank}{\colourshape}]{\colourshape};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \TestCommand[colourshape=triangle, nocolour=true]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is the desired outcome of my code, based on the pgfkeys arguments put into `TestCommand`:

[image: desired outcome of code]

So the code above should produce a triangle with a white fill. Instead I get the error `! Argument of \boolean has an extra }.` I know I can achieve the same result in a more verbose way by specifying a separate `pic` for each variant of the shape, but I would like to have a more compact solution, especially as there will be more style options to follow.

Comment: Ouch, you are overriding a lot of default TikZ keys.

Comment: @percusse I know, the real thing doesn't do this. It's a quick and dirty example. It works if I type in the style parameters manually rather than using the conditional, so it's OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to be certain without more information about the overall project. However, from your example, I would not use a conditional here at all. If you do use a conditional, I would look into PGF's `.is if` handler, which will make things much easier.

First some keys:

```
\tikzset{%
```

We can afford to use verbose names here because the user interface won't require them at all.

```
  Crazymoomin circle/.pic={\draw [fill=Crazymoomin@fill] (.5,.5) circle (0.5);},
  Crazymoomin square/.pic={\draw [fill=Crazymoomin@fill] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;},
  Crazymoomin triangle/.pic={\draw [fill=Crazymoomin@fill] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (0.5, 1) -- cycle;},
```

So that we can use simple key names in the user interface, we'll put them on a custom path, but we'll make sure that standard Ti*k*Z keys work here, too.

```
  /Crazymoomin/.search also={/tikz},
```

Switch paths.

```
  /Crazymoomin/.cd,
```

Now we can use simple names without overwriting the defaults.

```
  fill/.code={%
```

This will hold a custom colour.

```
    \colorlet{Crazymoomin@fill}{#1}%
  },
```

And a shape.

```
  shape/.store in=\Crazymoomin@shape,
```

To handle the colour/shape combo neatly, let's make `colour shape` a choice key.

```
  colour shape/.is choice,
```

Now for the options, which each switch to our path and set the `pic` shape and fill.

```
  colour shape/triangle/.style={/Crazymoomin/.cd, shape=triangle, fill=yellow},
  colour shape/circle/.style={/Crazymoomin/.cd, shape=circle, fill=red},
  colour shape/square/.style={/Crazymoomin/.cd, shape=square, fill=green},
```

`no colour` can just set the fill to white.

```
  no colour/.style={/Crazymoomin/fill=white},
```

Make sure we have a default for everything.

```
  fill=gray,
  shape=circle,
}
```

Now the command.

```
\newcommand{\TestCommand}[1][]{%
 \tikzset{%
```

Switch to our path.

```
   /Crazymoomin/.cd,
```

Default setting. This sets the filling colour anyway, so `no colour` is effectively false by default.

```
   colour shape=circle,
```

User options.

```
   #1,
 }%
```

And the `pic`.

```
 \pic {Crazymoomin \Crazymoomin@shape};
}
```

Then we can write, for example,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \TestCommand[colour shape=triangle, no colour]
 \scoped[xshift=12.5mm]{\TestCommand[colour shape=circle, no colour]}
 \scoped[xshift=25mm]{\TestCommand[colour shape=square, no colour]}
 \scoped[yshift=12.5mm]{\TestCommand[colour shape=triangle]}
 \scoped[xshift=12.5mm, yshift=12.5mm]{\TestCommand[colour shape=circle]}
 \scoped[xshift=25mm, yshift=12.5mm]{\TestCommand[colour shape=square]}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

to produce

[image: shape variations]

Obviously this is awkward because I didn't want to mess around too much with `\TextCommand` which doesn't have any positioning information (eek!?).

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
  Crazymoomin circle/.pic={\draw [fill=Crazymoomin@fill] (.5,.5) circle (0.5);},
  Crazymoomin square/.pic={\draw [fill=Crazymoomin@fill] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;},
  Crazymoomin triangle/.pic={\draw [fill=Crazymoomin@fill] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (0.5, 1) -- cycle;},
  /Crazymoomin/.search also={/tikz},
  /Crazymoomin/.cd,
  fill/.code={%
    \colorlet{Crazymoomin@fill}{#1}%
  },
  shape/.store in=\Crazymoomin@shape,
  colour shape/.is choice,
  colour shape/triangle/.style={/Crazymoomin/.cd, shape=triangle, fill=yellow},
  colour shape/circle/.style={/Crazymoomin/.cd, shape=circle, fill=red},
  colour shape/square/.style={/Crazymoomin/.cd, shape=square, fill=green},
  no colour/.style={/Crazymoomin/fill=white},
  fill=gray,
  shape=circle,
}
\newcommand{\TestCommand}[1][]{%
 \tikzset{%
   /Crazymoomin/.cd,
   colour shape=circle,
   #1,
 }%
 \pic {Crazymoomin \Crazymoomin@shape};
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \TestCommand[colour shape=triangle, no colour]
 \scoped[xshift=12.5mm]{\TestCommand[colour shape=circle, no colour]}
 \scoped[xshift=25mm]{\TestCommand[colour shape=square, no colour]}
 \scoped[yshift=12.5mm]{\TestCommand[colour shape=triangle]}
 \scoped[xshift=12.5mm, yshift=12.5mm]{\TestCommand[colour shape=circle]}
 \scoped[xshift=25mm, yshift=12.5mm]{\TestCommand[colour shape=square]}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, very helpful. I do change the outline pattern and colour using keys as well, but I have managed to get this to work because I'm changing separate style attributes. However, your method looks a lot more attractive so i'll see if I can do something similar for those. I wasn't planning on adding positioning information as they will probably either be drawn on their own or as part of a larger Tikz picture where I would expect positioning would be controlled out of scope of the command. I haven't decided yet if I'm going to include it.